# Paneldata regression where some variables have common unit roots

Tags: regression, panel-data, unit-root

I've got paneldata on Y, A, B, C. And I am trying to model dependent variable Y on independent variables A, B, C.

First I checked for unit roots (in Eviews).

Y, A, B, C have no individual unit roots, 
but Y has a common unit root, as well as A.

How should I continue?
 I already regressed Y on A, B, C but now I am hesitant since I'm not sure if I may do this, since Y and A have common unit roots.
Any help would be appreciated.

T=1900 (trading days)
N=90 (French stocks)
Y=liquidity measure
A=stock price. B=no. Shares C=some value/growth stock score

Comment: Can you please call the tests out by name? By a test of individual unit roots, presumably you mean the Im, Pesaran and Shin test, and by common unit root test, you mean the Lin, Levin and Chu type tests?

Comment: Correct. I'm sorry. Common: Levin Lin Chu, Breitung,
Inidividual: Im, Pesaran and Shin, Augmented Dickey Fuller (Fisher Chi-square), Phillips Perron (Fisher Chi-square).
Where the LLC test sais it may have a common unit root. 

Am I correct when I state that it is suggested in Levin, Lin and Chu(2002), "Unit root tests in panel data: Asymptotic and finite-sample properties" that for large T i should look at individual roots?

Comment: You will need to provide more information than this. Sizes and number of panels, the context, whether you tried panel cointegration tests...

Comment: I edited my first post to providd more details. If I'm not mistaken one should test for cointegration after testing for non-stationarity/unit roots, right?

Comment: Indeed so, but before running regressions. :)